# How to write SQL Function where YEAR(<date_column_name>) in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, strftime

I want to fetch data from database which has booking year is 2022, and the column I have is `tanggal_take` whose value format is 'Y-m-d', so I want to use `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE YEAR(tanggal_take) = "2022";` How to write it in laravel controller using Eloquent?

here is my code now

```
$data = Booking::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'bookings.id_member')
                            ->join('packages', 'packages.kode_paket', '=', 'bookings.kode_paket')
                            ->where( DB::raw('YEAR(bookings.tanggal_take)'), '=', $request->range )
                            ->get(['bookings.*', 'packages.*', 'users.*']);
```

The result is 0 but in database i have 4 datas with year 2022. I also already change `->where( DB::raw('YEAR(bookings.tanggal_take)'), '=', $request->range )` to `->whereYear('bookings.tanggal_take', '=', $request->range )` but still 0 result. Any hint? I will also looking for documentation by my self rn. Thanks

Comment: The where clause looks okay. Are you sure `$request->range` is 2022? And have you tested the code without the joins?

Comment: sorry, i found the root cause, its coz in my jquery code i forgot to sent checked radio button value, i wrote `$('input:radio[name=rangeReport]:').val();` but it should be `$('input:radio[name=rangeReport]:checked').val();`. So its always sent the first value of the radio button. Thanks for your help :)